# Add horizontal error bar to single point in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, errorbar

I have plotted 2 normal curves in `ggplot2`, and I've added a separate point at the maximum of the first curve. I want to add an error bar to this point which has width 1. Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
x=seq(from=0,to=5, length=100)
y=dnorm(x,2,0.5)
z=dnorm(x,3,1)
sf=data.frame(d=2,e=0.8, se=0.5)
normalplot=data.frame(x,y,z)
colnames(normalplot)=c("index", "Type 1", "Type 2")
k=melt(normalplot, id="index")
colnames(k)=c("index", "Method", "value")

ggplot(k, aes(x=index, y=value, colour=Method))+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+xlab("")+ylab("")+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(data=sf,aes(d,e),colour="red",size=2)+
  geom_errorbarh(sf,aes(xmax =d+se, xmin =d-se))
```

This does not work, but I cannot see why. I also want to add another point at the maximum of the second normal curve at (3,0.4) also with an error bar. Any help?

Comment: Thank you! I can now add the error bars, but the vertical ends are huge. Do you know how to cut them down?

Comment: Got it. Uses the `height` function. I was using width and wondering why it wasn't working - then remembered I was using horizontal bars. Thanks again.